# How to implement a shake animation to a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview, caanimation, shake

How to make a UITableViewCell shake from the left side to the right side?

I want the user to know that "this action isn't possible"!

Answer (score 7):

Thank you Hans One!. And here it is in Swift and in extension form to `UITableViewCell` with duration and path length selectable.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

extension UITableViewCell {
    func shake(duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.3, pathLength: CGFloat = 15) {
        let position: CGPoint = self.center

        let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(position.x, position.y))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(position.x-pathLength, position.y))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(position.x+pathLength, position.y))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(position.x-pathLength, position.y))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(position.x+pathLength, position.y))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(position.x, position.y))

        let positionAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")

        positionAnimation.path = path.CGPath
        positionAnimation.duration = duration
        positionAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)

        CATransaction.begin()
        self.layer.addAnimation(positionAnimation, forKey: nil)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution:

```
    CGPoint position = cell.center;

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(position.x, position.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(position.x-20, position.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(position.x+20, position.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(position.x-20, position.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(position.x+20, position.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(position.x, position.y)];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *positionAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    positionAnimation.path = path.CGPath;
    positionAnimation.duration = .5f;
    positionAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    [CATransaction begin];
    [cell.layer addAnimation:positionAnimation forKey:nil];
    [CATransaction commit];
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Swift 4 version of oyalhi’s protocol:

```swift
import UIKit

extension UITableViewCell {
    func shake(duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.3, pathLength: CGFloat = 15) {
        let position: CGPoint = self.center

        let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: position.x, y: position.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position.x-pathLength, y: position.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position.x+pathLength, y: position.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position.x-pathLength, y: position.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position.x+pathLength, y: position.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position.x, y: position.y))

        let positionAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")

        positionAnimation.path = path.cgPath
        positionAnimation.duration = duration
        positionAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)

        CATransaction.begin()
        self.layer.add(positionAnimation, forKey: nil)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a protocol based on the answer of @oyalhi with Swift 4:

```
protocol Shackable { }

extension Shackable where Self: UIView {

    func shake(duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.3, pathLength: CGFloat = 15) {
        let position = self.center
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: position.x, y: position.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position.x - pathLength, y: position.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position.x + pathLength, y: position.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position.x - pathLength, y: position.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position.x + pathLength, y: position.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position.x, y: position.y))

        let positionAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        positionAnimation.path = path.cgPath
        positionAnimation.duration = duration
        positionAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        CATransaction.begin()
        self.layer.add(positionAnimation, forKey: nil)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5. I found this solution.

1.Add this extensions

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
        
        func shake() {
            let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
            animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
            animation.duration = 0.6
            animation.values = [-20.0, 20.0, -20.0, 20.0, -10.0, 10.0, -5.0, 5.0, 0.0 ]
            layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
        }
         }
```

**2. In TableViewCell**

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
        if highlighted {
            if lockedState {
                shakedView.shake()
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]